# Semantics: Shop vs. Store Label

Tags: information-architecture

You're browsing a micro-site about the latest basketball shoe. You want to buy the basketball shoe and other accessories (e.g. headbands, socks, etc.) on the site. Shop is a verb and implies an action but viewing products doesn't mean buying products. Store is a noun and implies things you can buy. The other main site categories are nouns; getting people to buy the shoe online isn't a primary business goal. Do you use the main site category "Store" or "Shop"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More one for English stack exchange this IMO.

'Shop' isn't just a verb, it is also a noun. You can go shopping at the shops. You can say you buy your milk at the shop around the corner.

On 'store' vs. 'shop', I think this is something a little bit like 'mail' vs. 'post'.

Originally mail was just the American English version of post. It meant nothing different, it was purely a local variation. With the advent of email and the decline of posting actual letters however email became the principle form of mail and now mail is a pretty standard word in Europe (meaning email).

Store...this too was originally just American for shop. But again with the rise of the internet and online shopping, the word store came to take on digital connotations (for Europeans at least, I doubt the feeling is so strong in the US where brick and mortar stores remain). Despite the word we would use in Britain for a physical place being 'shop', to use 'shop' for something online...just feels a little off. Store is the usually seen term there. When shop is used for an online store...it just evokes quaint old fashioned vibes; which may be nice for shops selling certain things but probably not basketball shoes.

In this particular case- I guess "Visit our online store" (it doesn't mean you have to buy anything, don't be forceful and encourage people to browse) would be the thing to do.

"Shop for Nike goods"....it sounds a little forceful, like you actually are expected to buy something.

Comment: store is also a verb,and it means the storing of items. the store is where the items are located. so if your website behaves like a store it should be called a store. and if its a shop call it a shop. or a market perhaps. this is more english than UX therefor i think this question doesnt 100% fit in here. it just has to do with context.

Answer (score 1):

I think a **Store** makes quite a lot of sense rather than Shop.

If you're concentrating on Branding and having your own product to sell, go with **Store**.

These terms are generally used interchangeably.

Google, for example, doesn't own a retail store, so they emulate their experience online with a store selling their most celebrated products.

[image: Google Store]

To sum it up, Shopping makes more sense when it comes to SEO since one is certain to search for "Online Shopping" more than "Online Store".

However, if you have your own brand and do not have a physical retail store for the same, you could name your online shopping experience as a Store and have a great branding potential to it.